# Steam at 1 MPa, 300°C flows through a 30 cm diameter pipe with an average velocity of 10 m/s. The mass flow rate of this steam is:

Tags: thermodynamics

Steam at 1 MPa, 300°C flows through a 30 cm diameter pipe with an average velocity of 10 m/s. The
mass flow rate of this steam is:

A) 0.731 kg/s B) 2.74 kg/s
C) 3.18 kg/s D) 3.78 kg/s

Can anyone help me out please?

I thought I had to use m=PVA 
P=1000 pa
V=0.2579 (property table)
A= pi*15^2
So m=1000*0.2579*((pi*15^2)/1000)= 183 kg/s which is not correct.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the formula.Check the terms in the formula for mass flow rate.

Comment: So you could explain it to me please?

Comment: is there a difference between ((pi*15^2)/1000) and (pi*(15/1000)^2)) ? Which should you use.